# Yast2 broken (after zypper dup ?)

Tags: linux, opensuse, yast

Not sure if related to the last update (zypper dup) of my openSUSE Leap 15.0, but now all yast2 subcommands fail with this error (yast2 alone will bring up the screen but selecting any subcommand fails too):

```
erle:~ # yast2 sound
The config 'root' does not exist. Likely snapper is not configured.
See 'man snapper' for further instructions.
Traceback (most recent call last):
        11: from /usr/lib/YaST2/bin/y2start:11:in `<main>'
        10: from /usr/lib64/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
         9: from /usr/lib64/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
         8: from /usr/lib64/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.5.0/yast.rb:30:in `<top (required)>'
         7: from /usr/lib64/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
         6: from /usr/lib64/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
         5: from /usr/lib64/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.5.0/yast/builtins.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
         4: from /usr/lib64/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
         3: from /usr/lib64/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
         2: from /usr/lib64/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.5.0/yast/i18n.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
         1: from /usr/lib64/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
/usr/lib64/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot load such file -- fast_gettext (LoadError)
```

I've seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45380062/opensuse-rvm-yast2-collision and the related https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/526198-Yast2-Ruby-Problem-After-Update, but I only have one ruby version:

```
erle:~ #  zypper lr -d 
Repository priorities are without effect. All enabled repositories share the same priority.

# | Alias                             | Name                              | Enabled | GPG Check | Refresh | Priority | Type   | URI                                                                                    | Service
--+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+---------+-----------+---------+----------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------
1 | Oss                               | Oss                               | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | No      |   99     | rpm-md | http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/leap/15.0/repo/oss/                          |        
2 | dvd                               | dvd                               | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | Yes     |   99     | rpm-md | http://opensuse-guide.org/repo/openSUSE_Leap_15.0/                                     |        
3 | gcc                               | gcc                               | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | No      |   99     | rpm-md | http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/gcc/openSUSE_Leap_15.0                |        
4 | mozilla                           | mozilla                           | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | No      |   99     | rpm-md | http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/mozilla/openSUSE_Leap_15.0                   |        
5 | openSUSE-Leap-42.2-Update         | openSUSE-Leap-15.0-Update         | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | Yes     |   99     | rpm-md | http://download.opensuse.org/update/leap/15.0/oss/                                     |        
6 | openSUSE-Leap-42.2-Update-Non-Oss | openSUSE-Leap-15.0-Update-Non-Oss | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | Yes     |   99     | rpm-md | http://download.opensuse.org/update/leap/15.0/non-oss/                                 |        
7 | packman                           | packman                           | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | Yes     |   99     | rpm-md | http://packman.inode.at/suse/openSUSE_Leap_15.0/                                       |        
8 | x2go                              | x2go                              | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | No      |   99     | rpm-md | https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/X11:/RemoteDesktop:/x2go/openSUSE_Leap_15.0 |        
erle:~ # zypper se -si ruby
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...

S  | Name                            | Type    | Version              | Arch   | Repository               
---+---------------------------------+---------+----------------------+--------+--------------------------
i  | libruby2_5-2_5                  | package | 2.5.0-lp150.2.11     | x86_64 | Oss                      
i+ | libstorage-ng-ruby              | package | 3.3.317-lp150.2.15.1 | x86_64 | openSUSE-Leap-15.0-Update
i  | ruby                            | package | 2.5-lp150.1.5        | x86_64 | Oss                      
i  | ruby-common                     | package | 2.1-lp150.3.1        | noarch | Oss                      
i+ | ruby-devel                      | package | 2.5-lp150.1.5        | x86_64 | Oss                      
i  | ruby2.5                         | package | 2.5.0-lp150.2.11     | x86_64 | Oss                      
i  | ruby2.5-devel                   | package | 2.5.0-lp150.2.11     | x86_64 | Oss                      
i  | ruby2.5-rubygem-abstract_method | package | 1.2.1-lp150.1.9      | x86_64 | Oss                      
i  | ruby2.5-rubygem-cfa             | package | 0.6.4-lp150.1.1      | x86_64 | Oss                      
i  | ruby2.5-rubygem-cfa_grub2       | package | 1.0.1-lp150.2.3.1    | x86_64 | openSUSE-Leap-15.0-Update
i  | ruby2.5-rubygem-cheetah         | package | 0.5.0-lp150.1.11     | x86_64 | Oss                      
i  | ruby2.5-rubygem-fast_gettext    | package | 1.6.0-lp150.1.4      | x86_64 | Oss                      
i  | ruby2.5-rubygem-gem2rpm         | package | 0.10.1-lp150.3.30    | x86_64 | Oss                      
i  | ruby2.5-rubygem-ruby-augeas     | package | 0.5.0-lp150.1.12     | x86_64 | Oss                      
i  | ruby2.5-rubygem-ruby-dbus       | package | 0.14.0-lp150.1.6     | x86_64 | Oss                      
i  | ruby2.5-rubygem-simpleidn       | package | 0.0.9-lp150.1.2      | x86_64 | Oss                      
i  | ruby2.5-stdlib                  | package | 2.5.0-lp150.2.11     | x86_64 | Oss                      
i+ | xmms2-ruby                      | package | 0.8-lp150.2.8        | x86_64 | Oss                      
i+ | yast2-ruby-bindings             | package | 4.0.6-lp150.1.1      | x86_64 | Oss
```

How can I repair yast2?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the question, I think I found a solution. The missing fast_gettext should be part of the ruby2.5-rubygem-fast_gettext package:

```
erle:~ # rpm -ql ruby2.5-rubygem-fast_gettext
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.5.0/build_info
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.5.0/cache/fast_gettext-1.6.0.gem
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/fast_gettext-1.6.0
...
```

However, on my system it did not exist:

```
erle:~ # ll /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems
total 68
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jul  4  2018 bundler-1.16.2
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Nov 28 10:17 cfa_grub2-1.0.1
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Jul  4  2018 chunky_png-1.3.10
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Jul  4  2018 compass-1.0.3
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Jul  4  2018 compass-core-1.0.3
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jul  4  2018 compass-import-once-1.0.5
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Jul  4  2018 ffi-1.8.1
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Jul  4  2018 ffi-1.9.0
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Jul  4  2018 ffi-1.9.17
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jul  4  2018 ffi-1.9.25
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jul  4  2018 multi_json-1.13.1
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jul  4  2018 rb-fsevent-0.10.3
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jul  4  2018 rb-inotify-0.9.10
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun 27  2018 rdoc-6.0.1
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Jul  4  2018 sass-3.4.25
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Nov 28 10:22 suse-connect-0.3.12
```

So I reinstalled the package

```
erle:~ # zypper install --force ruby2.5-rubygem-fast_gettext
```

After that, a yast2 popup complained about missing 'abstract_method'. Not knowing what else got deleted, I reinstalled all ruby-related packages

```
zypper in --force libruby2_5-2_5 libstorage-ng-ruby ruby ruby-common ruby-devel ruby2.5 ruby2.5-devel ruby2.5-rubygem-abstract_method ruby2.5-rubygem-cfa ruby2.5-rubygem-cfa_grub2 ruby2.5-rubygem-cheetah ruby2.5-rubygem-fast_gettext ruby2.5-rubygem-gem2rpm ruby2.5-rubygem-ruby-augeas ruby2.5-rubygem-ruby-dbus ruby2.5-stdlib ruby2.5-rubygem-simpleidn yast2-ruby-bindings
```

And now yast2 is operational again. What remains a mystery is how the files were lost.